# Given $X\sim\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)=N+Y$, what is $P(Y<y)$?

Tags: probability

Let $X\sim\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$ $(\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^+)$ be an exponential random variable, such that $[X]=N\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $Y=X-N\in[0,1)$, where $[\cdot]$ is the floor function. I am required to find the probability that $P(Y<y)$ where $y\in[0,1)$.

I am **not** interested in a solution, I just want to understand why is my solution incorrect:

First, I found (correctly) that $P(N=n)=(1-e^{-\lambda})e^{-\lambda n}$. Then, I claimed that:

$$P(Y<y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(X-N<y\mid N=n)P(N=n)=(1-e^{-\lambda})\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[e^{-\lambda n}\cdot\lambda\int_{n}^{n+y}e^{-\lambda x}\ dx\right]=(1-e^{-\lambda})\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[e^{-\lambda n}(e^{-\lambda n}-e^{-\lambda n -\lambda y})\right]=(1-e^{-\lambda})(1-e^{-\lambda y})\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-2\lambda n}=(1-e^{-\lambda y})\frac{1-e^{-\lambda}}{1-e^{-2\lambda}}=\frac{1-e^{-\lambda y}}{1+e^{-\lambda}}$$

This answer can't be correct, since $P(Y<1)$ should be $1$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: there is a sign error at the very last step.

Comment: @Mick I know that, but I made sure quite a few times that I computed the series correctly. So the problem is not with computing the series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the $X$ and $N$ are not independent.

$$ P(Y<y) = \sum_{n\geq 0} P(X\in [n,n+y)) = \sum_{n\ge 0} e^{-\lambda n} - e^{\lambda (n+y)} = \sum_{n\ge 0} e^{-\lambda n}(1-e^{-\lambda y})= \frac{1-e^{-\lambda y}}{1-e^{-\lambda}} \quad \mbox{for } y<1$$

whereas

$$ \mathbb P(X -N<y | N=n) = \frac{P(X-N<y, N=n)}{P(N=n)} = \frac{e^{-\lambda n} -e^{-\lambda(n+y)}}{e^{-\lambda n}(1-e^{-\lambda})} $$
this does not equal 
$$ e^{-\lambda n}- e^{-\lambda(n+y)} $$as you suggest.

Comment: Thank you, my problem was the second line that you wrote

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $0<y<1$
$$
\{Y < y \} = \{X - N < y\} = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty \{n<X<n+y\},
$$
and this union is disjoint. So
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y<y) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb P(n<X<n+y)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(e^{-\lambda n} - e^{-\lambda(n+y)}\right)\\
&= \frac{e^{\lambda(1-y)} \left(e^{\lambda  y}-1\right)}{e^{\lambda }-1}.
\end{align}